# The variance of sample mean ($\bar y$) is given by $Var(\bar y) = \frac{1}{n}(1 - f)S_y^2$

Tags: variance, sampling, covariance

I saw a proof in a text that the variance of sample mean ($\bar y$) is given by

$Var(\bar y) = \frac{1}{n}(1 - f)S_y^2$

where

$S_y^2 = \frac {1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i -\bar Y)^2$

and

$f = \frac{n}{N}$

I'm stuck in some of the steps from

$Var(\bar y) = \frac{1}{n}[\sum_{i=1}^nE(Z_i^2) + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE(Z_iZ_j)]$

where

$Z_i= y_i -\bar Y$

and

$Z_j= y_j -\bar Y$

especially considering the covariance

$2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE(Z_iZ_j)$

Given $Z_i$ the conditional value of $Z_j$ being

$E[Z_j|Z_i] = \frac{E[Z_iZ_j]}{E[Z_i]}$

$E[Z_iZ_j] = E_1[Z_iE_2(Z_j|Z_i)] = E_1[Z_i\frac{\sum_{i\neq1}^nZ_j}{N-1}] = -\frac{1}{N}S_y^2$

I'm quite lost here

Comment: What are $Z_i$ and $Z_j$? What is the difference between $\bar y and \bar Y$ (also $n$ and $N$)?

Comment: I just edited the question to include the values of $Z_i$ and $Z_j$. $\bar y$ and $\bar Y$ are the sample mean and population mean respectively. $n$ is the sample size drawn from a population $N$.